# javascript - Change the font color of the last word typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok I am making a text editor and have to try and make the last word typed change font color based on if it's a keyword or not... I have tried multiple solutions to this but nothing has prevailed... Here is what I have tried so far

```
function getLastWord() {
        var input = document.getElementById("my_text").value;
        //var input = document.getElementById(textArea.value);

        var inputValue = input.value;
        var lastWordTyped
        var changeColorOfWord;
        var ele = document.querySelector("#my_text");

        //ele.style.color = "blue"

        if (input == null) {
            input == " ";
        }

        lastWordTyped = input.substr(input.trim().lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
        //lastWordTyped = inputValue.substr(inputValue.trim().lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        if (input != null) {

            for (var i = 0; i < reservedKeyWords.length; i++) {
                if ( lastWordTyped == reservedKeyWords[i] ) {

                    //changeColor(lastWordTyped);
                    //my_text.replace(inputValue, lastWordTyped);
                    //ele.fieldNameElement.innerHTML = lastWordTyped;
                    //ele.innerHTML = lastWordTyped;
                    ele.innerHTML.fontcolor = 'Blue';
                    return;

                } else if (lastWordTyped !== reservedKeyWords[i]) {

                    //ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(lastWordTyped, '<span style="color:black"></span>');
                    //resetFontColor();


                }


            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried this function (found from SO)

```
function changeColor(word) {
        var ele = document.querySelector("my_text");
        ele.onkeypress = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                //the setTimeout is so the content is inserted before execution
                document.getElementById('view_text').value = ele.textContent;
                if (ele.innerHTML.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
                    ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(word, '<span style="color:blue">' + word + '</span>');
                }
            }, 50);
        }
        }
```

Also I have tried this one:

```
function colorMyKeyword(keywordColor, text) {

        return '<span style="color:' + keywordColor + '>' + text + '</span>';
    }
```

None of these functions have gotten the job done though. I have it now so that it will change the text color to blue but then the problem is that it changes ALL of the text to blue after that word...

I would prefer this to be in javascript as I do not know how to use JQuery, or really CSS for that matter or even know how to write it..

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: this could help you: http://codepen.io/mel/pen/uAlIn/ - includes the javascript you're looking for

Comment: When you actively type, you're going to create a lot of "last" words.  You need to remove the class (styling) on all the previous words before adding the styling to the last word.  Recommendation is to use a class and not inline styling as you're doing there.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated code based on comment(s) below (changed to div from input)**

Not the best code in the world but it should work.  The CSS should probably be done by adding a class instead of changing the `style` attribute.

```
<div id="my_text">This is some text</div>

var isKeyword = false;
var el = document.getElementById('my_text');
var arr = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
var lastWordTyped = arr.pop();

/* replace with yours*/
var reservedKeyWords = ['text','another','word', 'here'];


for (var i = 0, len = reservedKeyWords.length ; i < len ; i++) {
  if ( lastWordTyped == reservedKeyWords[i] ) {
    lastWordTyped = '<span style="color:blue">'+lastWordTyped +'</span>'; //update color
    arr.push(lastWordTyped);
    isKeyword = true;
  }
}
if (!isKeyword) { arr.push(lastWordTyped); } //put original back
el.innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can get the last word just fine, no problems there, I just cant change ONLY that word if it needs to be change without changing the rest of the text

Comment: Tried your updated code all that it did was replace whatever I typed in the text area with `'<span style="color:blue">' + lastWordTyped + '</span>'`

Comment: what kind of input accepts span tags in its value? I was trying to do it in a contenteditable div but I've got issues with carret positionning

Comment: @Kaiido This is based off the OP's original code.  It is more how to color the last word vs how to get the content.

Comment: @bbesase  check out this fiddle.  I updated the code to get the innerHTMl from a div.  http://jsfiddle.net/7y9xatch/1/

Comment: @GaryStorey Ok, but it can not work while typing as if you change innerHTML, carret will return to start check [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y9xatch/2/)

Comment: @Kaiido  Agreed.  However, none of that was stated as a requirement.  Only how to color the last word. If you changed the event to `blur` in your fiddle, then this would work.  I would discourage anything like this while someone is actively typing.

Comment: from question title : "Change the font color of the last word **typed**" So, yes it was stated. And if the goal is a texteditor I'm pretty much sure it has to run when actively typing as lastword typed might not be the real last typed one when blur this text editor

Comment: @Kaiido Good point. Of course if you are typing every key pressed is potentially the last word.  Sounds like OP needs a full fledged parser.

Comment: @GaryStorey Wow finally I got something from your code : http://jsfiddle.net/7y9xatch/4/ maybe OP will be interested too

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED: Do the whole thing on keyup**

here's a simple example that you can use: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3too1y31/1/)**

```
$('#text').keyup(function(){
    $('#result').html($('#text').val());
    var splittedText=$('#result').html().split(/\s/);
    var lastWord=splittedText[splittedText.length-1]; 
    $('#result').html($('#result').html().replace(lastWord,'<span>'+lastWord+'</span>'));
    $('#result').children('span').css('color',$('#color').val());
});
```

you need to write a sentence in the first input and a hexa-deciaml color in the second one.(including the # at the beginning)

Comment: You should split on `/\s/` since your space character may not be the same as what's typed in the text field

Comment: So instead of using a button how would you do this on `spacebar keydown`? Sorry I don't know `JQuery` so this looks super confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to answer your questions :
I am using [@GaryStorey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220305/3702797) as it was a better starting point than what I add (I do like `pop`&`push`).
The problem with his answer were that it only showed how to change the color but it wasn't relevant on how to do it in an input nor in a contenteditable element.

So here are my adjustements, with a `setCaret` function to deal with the fact that caret always returns to start if we do change the innerHTML of edited element.

**Be carefull, it is still very buggy and you should not use it in any production**,
 however it can give you a good starting point.

```js
var reservedKeyWords = ['text', 'another', 'word', 'here'];
        var el = document.getElementById('my_text');
        el.addEventListener('keyup', function (evt) {
            if (evt.keyCode == 32 || evt.keyCode == 13) {
                var isKeyword = false;
                var arr = el.innerHTML.split(/\s/);
                var lastWordTyped = arr.pop();
                lastWordTyped = lastWordTyped.replace('&nbsp;', '');
                for (var i = 0, len = reservedKeyWords.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (lastWordTyped == reservedKeyWords[i]) {
                        lastWordTyped = '<span style="color:blue">' + lastWordTyped + '</span>'; //update color
                        arr.push(lastWordTyped);
                        isKeyword = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!isKeyword) {
                    arr.push(lastWordTyped);
                } //put original back
                el.innerHTML = arr.join(' ') + '&nbsp;';
                setCaret(el);
            }
        });

        function setCaret(el) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            var endNode = el.lastChild;
            range.selectNodeContents(endNode);
            range.setStart(endNode, range.endOffset);
            range.setEnd(endNode, range.endOffset);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
```

```css
#my_text {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    border : dashed 0.5px grey;
}
```

```html
<p> list of KeyWords : 'text', 'another', 'word', 'here';</p>
<span id="my_text" contenteditable="true">Edit me using "reservedKeyWords" defined in JS</span>
```

Oh and note that I am using a `span` instead of a `div`, because `div` tag adds some `<br>` from nowhere after the textNode.